# how to use "this" to MovieClip(root)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this

```
function fl1(floor)
{
this.("fl"+floor).visible=true;
}
```

how to visible it, if the location of the object in "MovieClip(root)"

i try this, but is'nt work... (sorry of my bad english)

```
function fl1(floor)
{
this.("MovieClip(root).fl"+floor).visible=true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
this["fl" + floor].visible = true
```

In general, if you want to access the property by the instance name, then you should use the array subscript operator ( [] ) directly on the object without using dot (.)

Answer (score 0):

What is floor's variable type passed to the function fl1?

If it is String and you construct the name of the object which visibility you want to change you need to use getChildByName.

```
var myFloor:* = parentObject.getChildByName(floor);
if(myFloor)myFloor.visible = true;
```

To access so called root, you can use stage property of any object added to display list.

```
var root = this.stage;
```

If floor is already object, you simply:

```
floor.visible = true;
```